# Why the slideshow don't appear in my custom theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress theme developing and I have the following problem.

I am trying to create a WordPress theme that used **BootStrap** CSS framework based on this BootStrap demo static website (I have the entire source of this site because it is a downlodable tutorial): http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

This is my **custom WP theme**: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

So I have create a basic WP theme and as first stage I want to insert the **slideshow** of the previous demo page in the **header.php** file of my WP theme, so this is my **header.php** code:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> » Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
<!-- leave this for stats -->

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Sezione slider con Flexslider -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-2.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-3.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
           </p>
           </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

<center>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
</div>
<hr />
```

As you can see I have simply take the  block of the static demo website and I have put it at the beginning of my **header.php** file.

Ok, my WordPress theme is configured to use the BootStrap CSS and the **flexslider.css** and also the **style2.css** file that represent what in the demo website is the **stili-custom.css** (my custom CSS settings that is loaded at last to ovverride the definied properties)

As you can see the problem is that at the beginning of my theme the slide show not appear and I have no idea about this issue.

Why? Can you help me to solve this problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the call that activates Flexslider. You could put this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

See the full documentation here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some better code for use within your template pages. It is a loop that outputs your posts featured images. If you don't want to get featured images then remove the PHP and hard code yours instead. Use as you wish.

```
<!-- Flexslider Slider -->
    <section class="slider">
    <div id="timeline" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

      <?php
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $post_thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>
           <li>
             <div class="slider-img" style="background: transparent url(<?php echo $post_thumbnail_url ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>
            <div class="caption-wrapper">

              <a class="toggle">
              <h2 class="caps"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
              </a>

              <div class="caption-content">
              <p><?php ?><br /> 
              <span class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></span></p> 
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              </div>

            </div>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end #timeline -->
    </section>
<!-- End Flexslider Slider -->
```

Initialize Flexslider in your JS:

```
$('#timeline').flexslider({
 // animation: "slide",
 // controlNav: false,
 // directionNav: false,
 // slideshow: false,
 // animationLoop: false,
 // touch: true,
 // keyboard: true,
 // // controlsContainer: ".controls-container",
 // sync: "#carousel",
 // start: function(slider){  },
 //      before: function(){  }
});
```